# JSOM function not getting called

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, client-object-model

I have two functions in my js file. Each function is used to fetch data from list. The first function is called as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getSWDocs);
});
getSWDocsSuccess = function () {

var listItemEnumeratorlistReady = SFWData.collListItems.getEnumerator(),
   count = collListItems.get_count();

var listItemInfo = '';
DocList = new Array();

while (listItemEnumeratorlistReady.moveNext()) {
    swItem = listItemEnumeratorlistReady.get_current();
    var tempArray = new Array(4);

    tempArray[0] = documentType;
    tempArray[1] = swItem.get_item("FileRef");
    tempArray[2] = swItem.get_item("Title");
    tempArray[3] = swItem.get_item("SWSortOrder");

    DocList.push(tempArray);
}

    setColorDetails();      
    var serviceType = $('#pagetype').val();
    setDivId(serviceType);
    getDocuments(serviceType);
}
```

The second function is called in the success method of this function. There are other functions that have a dependency on this function and so I have called this function before the dependent functions. But still the caml query fired does not invoke the success function even if there is no issue.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you use `SOD` to wait for __sp.js__ then you call `getSWDocs`, but in this file you define `getSWDocsSuccess` ... does this mean `getSWDocs` calls `getSWDocsSuccess`?

Comment: @Mancy You have specified getSWDocs as a callback method while you have implemented getSWDocsSuccess().

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getSWDocs);
```

with

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getSWDocsSuccess);
```